# PythonにてSeleniumのrequests.exceptions.SSLErrorを解消したい

Tags: python, python3, selenium

PythonでSeleniumを使って下記のWEBサイトをスクレイピングしています。

https://shoply.co.jp/

エクセルからJAN_CODEを読み込んで、サイトへJAN_CODEを検索して、画像・商品名・価格をエクセルに入れています。

エクセルデータ

```
JAN_CODE,画像,商品名,価格
4953103354739
4953103289055
4589591675799
4589591675126
4589591675430
```

実行しましたら、最初は問題なく操作されます。
1分ぐらい経ちますと、**requests.exceptions.SSLError:** のエラーが表示されます。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\test\Desktop\test1.py", line 37, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)

File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 32, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_path(self.driver)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\manager.py", line 19, in _get_driver_path
    binary_path = self.driver_cache.find_driver(driver)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\driver_cache.py", line 74, in find_driver
    driver_version = driver.get_version()
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\driver.py", line 39, in get_version
    self.get_latest_release_version()
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\driver.py", line 72, in get_latest_release_version
    resp = requests.get(
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_103.0.5060 (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

ドライバに問題ありますでしょうか。

pip installやpythonのpackagesを最新に試しても同じエラーが表示されます。

```
pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (22.2)
```

```
pip install pyOpenSSL --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL in c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (22.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=35.0 in c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyOpenSSL) (37.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=35.0->pyOpenSSL) (1.14.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=35.0->pyOpenSSL) (2.20)
```

import sslも入れましたが、それでもダメでした。

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

requests.exceptions.SSLErrorを解消できる方法ありますでしょうか。
もし分かる方がいましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

御手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

全体のコード

```
from cmath import exp
from email.mime import image
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import requests
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import uuid
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context


#エクセル
file_excel=r"C:\Users\test\Desktop\test.xlsx"

#画像挿入するエクセルファイルを指定
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_excel)
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

#1行ずつ読み込み
#2行目からループを行う
for i in range(2022,ws.max_row+1):
 
 options = Options()
 options.add_argument('--headless')
 options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
 options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
     
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)

 #JAN_CODE a列を読み込む
 JAN_CODE = ws['a'+str(i)].value

 #画像 b列を読み込む
 image_excdel = ws['b'+str(i)].value
 
 #url指定
 #url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+row.JAN_CODE
 url="https://shoply.co.jp/"
 #url="https://shoply.co.jp/"+str(JAN_CODE)+"の価格と最安値"
 print(url)
 
 #検索サイトを開く
 driver.get(url)
 
 #5秒待機
 time.sleep(5)

 #商品名検索
 shyohinmai_kensaku=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js-tp-sbar"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(str(JAN_CODE))

 time.sleep(2)

 kensaku_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js-tp-sbar"]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]').click()

 time.sleep(5)

 try:
   #画像取得
   gazou=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="result-list"]/ul/li[1]/div/a/div[3]/img')
   print(gazou)
   
   img_url = gazou.get_attribute('src')

   #unique作成
   unique=str(uuid.uuid4())[-6:]
   
   #画像保存
   file_image = r"C:\Users\test\Desktop\Image\Image"+unique+".jpg"

   response = requests.get(img_url)
   image = response.content

   with open(file_image, "wb") as aaa:
     aaa.write(image)

   #挿入する画像を指定
   img = Image(file_image)
   
   img.width = 100
   img.height = 100
   
   #画像挿入
   ws.add_image(img, 'b'+str(i))
   
   #商品名取得
   shyohinmai=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="result-list"]/ul/li[1]/div/a/div[4]/span[2]').text
   print(shyohinmai)
   
   #Excelへ書き込み
   ws['c'+str(i)].value = shyohinmai
   
   #価格取得
   kakaku=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="result-list"]/ul/li[1]/div/a/div[5]/span').text
   print(kakaku)
   
   #Excelへ書き込み
   ws['d'+str(i)].value = kakaku
   
   #xlsx書き出し
   wb.save(file_excel)
   
   driver.close()
 
 except:
   driver.close()
```

Comment: この記事を試してみてはどうでしょう？ [Pythonのrequestsでverify=Falseを使わずにSSLの検証を無効化する](https://qiita.com/hrappuccino/items/84e3a5113b871037024a) まずは元になったように`requests.get()`のパラメータに`verify=False`を加えてみるとか。

Comment: いつも回答ありがとうございます。
`driver.get(url,verify=False)`で試してみましたがエラーしました。`requests`にしか利用できないようです。

Comment: そうすると次は紹介記事のように呼び出す前に環境変数を変更しておくのを試してみるくらいですかね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。環境変数も試してみます。

Comment: 試してみましたが、ダメした。他の方法あるかどうか。調べてみます。